# Send a collection from emit in livewire apparently sends additional information

Tags: laravel, events, parameters, laravel-livewire

I have a simple dropdown as a livewire component (say component A):

```
<select wire:model="mould_id" wire:change="$emit('mouldSelected', mould_id)" class="form-control w-75 float-left">
    @foreach( $moulds as $mould )
        <option value="{{ $mould->id }}">{{ $mould->code }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

The component's class receives a collection of moulds to display the select, but also, when the `mouldsUpdated` is fired, the list should be updated. This event should be fired with the list of moulds in another component.

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Livewire\Orders;

    use App\Models\Mould;
    use Livewire\Component;

    class OrderMouldSelect extends Component{
        public $moulds       = [];
        public $mould_id     = null;

        protected $listeners = [
            'mouldsUpdated' => 'setMoulds',
        ];

        /**
         * Sets the component up
         *
         * @param $moulds
         */
        public function mount( $moulds ){
            $this->setMoulds( $moulds );
        }

        /**
         * Sets the list of moulds for the dropdown menu
         *
         * @param $moulds
         */
        public function setMoulds( $moulds ){
            $this->moulds = $moulds;
        }

        /**
         * Displays the mould selector dropdown
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
         */
        public function render(){
            return view( 'livewire.orders.order-mould-select' );
        }
    }
```

So, in my B component I have a method called `FilterMoulds`, which applies some filters to the moulds collection and then emits `mouldsUpdated` with the filtered moulds as a parameter:

```
    /**
     * Updates the list of moulds
     */
    public function filterMoulds(){
        $filters                = $this->filters;
        $this->moulds           = $this->family->moulds->filter( function( $mould ) use( $filters ){
            ...
            ...
        } );
        $this->emit( 'mouldsUpdated', $this->moulds );
    }
```

This method is launched by a `<select>` in component's B blade:

```
<select class="form-control" wire:model="filter_value" wire:change="setFilter('{{ $characteristic->parameter->symbol }}')">
    <option value="">Choose a characteristic</option>
    @foreach( $characteristic->data[ 'values'] as $value )
        <option value="{{ $value }}" @if( array_key_exists( $characteristic->parameter->symbol, $filters ) && ( $filters[ $characteristic->parameter->symbol ] == $value ) ) class="bg-primary" selected @endif>
            {{ $value }} {{ $characteristic->parameter->symbol }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

When I execute the action to filter the moulds I get this error:

**ErrorException
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: \Path\To\My\Project\resources\views\livewire\orders\order-mould-select.blade.php)**

So I tried die and dump the $moulds variable in `setMoulds` method and I get this (I will attach an image that explains more the dump):
[image: In the file you can clearly see that the collection is not the only thing being passed in the $moulds variable]

Answer (score 0):

try this in class OrderMouldSelect

```
public function mount(Mould $mould ){
     $this-> moulds = $mould->orderBy('id','asc')->pluck('code','id');
}
```

in blade

```
    <select wire:model="mould_id" class="custom-select @error('mould_id') is-invalid @enderror">
       <option value="" readonly="true" hidden="true" selected>{{__('section.select')}}</option>
          @if(! empty($moulds) && $moulds->count())
             @foreach($moulds as $key => $value)
                <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
             @endforeach
          @endif
   </select>

    @error('mould_id') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
```